# Watching YouTube clips on Firefox uses around 20% of CPU power

Tags: 14.04, firefox, youtube

Watching 1080p videos on YouTube, using Mozilla Firefox for Ubuntu 47.0, on my notebook with i7-4700MQ CPU @ 2.40GHz × 8 and 8 GiB of RAM, running Ubuntu LTS 14.04, the Gnome System Monitor says that Firefox takes up about 20% of my CPU and almost one GiB of memory (that's a lot of details, I know). Is this normal? What is to be expected of alternatives like Chrome for Ubuntu?

Comment: ehm install chrome (or better: chromium) and check it out yourself? and is there reason to believe 20% is too much? and ... if you want comparing percentages you should really provide the video you base your results on... otherwise you'd have different compression rates, codecs and more things that will impair a conclusion.

Comment: 1: Installed chromium and tried myself, cpu usage is up to 25-30% but memory usage is down to 350 MiB. 2: No idea if 20% is to be expected, I'm asking the community. 3: I've experienced this with all 1080p videos I've found. The one right now is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y-yv6VB0Gtg which is also at 60fps.

Comment: but chromium will go up quickly when you start using a 2nd and 3rd tab? ;-)

Comment: lol. Can't really see a difference, I'll probably stick with firefox cause it has all of my addons and saved passwords

Answer (score 1):

Linux reports CPU usage per cpu/core/thread, so you can easily have multiple processes reporting 100% if it pegs each core, where Windows divides the usage by the total number of cores so that the total usage adds up to 100%.  So on a quad core (1 thread per core) 20% usage on Linux would show up as 5% usage on Windows.

I easily hit 30-35% usage on Chrome on an HD video with i7-3540M CPU @ 3.00GHz.

As far as memory usage, Firefox has all of its memory in a single process, Chrome breaks it out into multiple processes for each tab and plugin so it is hard to get a good idea of usage between the two.  My Youtube process is about 1G in memory for that tab.